# MATLAB write multipage tiff exponentially slow

Tags: matlab, tiff, libtiff

I am trying to write a single multipage tiff file which is 128 pixels x 128 pixels x 122000 frames of 16-bit unsigned integers.  ImageJ or a short Python script can do this in less than one minute on a fast machine. On the same machine, MATLAB would likely take days to do so using any method I have tried.  Here is what I have tried so far:

**Use imwrite to write IMG to test.tif (recommended by MATLAB documentation)**

```
    tic
    numframes=size(IMG,3);
    divider=10^(floor(log10(numframes))-1);
    imwrite(IMG(:,:,1),'test.tif');
    for i=2:numframes;
        imwrite(IMG(:,:,i),'test.tif','WriteMode','append');
        if (round(i/divider)==i/divider)
            fprintf('Frame %d written in %.0f seconds, %2d percent complete, time                 left=%.0f seconds \n', ...
                i, toc, i/numframes*100, (numframes - i)/(i/toc));
        end
    end
```

which results in the following output:

> Frame 10000 written in 104 seconds, 8.196721e+00 percent complete,
>   time left=1163 seconds Frame 20000 written in 296 seconds,
>   1.639344e+01 percent complete, time left=1509 seconds  Frame 30000 written in 590 seconds, 2.459016e+01 percent complete, time left=1809
>   seconds  Frame 40000 written in 1035 seconds, 3.278689e+01 percent
>   complete, time left=2121 seconds  Frame 50000 written in 1682 seconds,
>   4.098361e+01 percent complete, time left=2421 seconds

Notice the exponential increase in time as more frames are written.

**Use the Tiff class directly**

```
    if bigtiff
        t = Tiff(fname,'w8');
    else
        t = Tiff(fname,'w');
    end
    tagstruct.ImageLength = size(image,1);
    tagstruct.ImageWidth = size(image,2);
    tagstruct.Photometric = Tiff.Photometric.MinIsBlack;
    if bitspersamp==16
        tagstruct.BitsPerSample = 16;
    end
    if bitspersamp==32
        tagstruct.BitsPerSample = 32;
    end
    tagstruct.SamplesPerPixel = 1;
    tagstruct.RowsPerStrip = 256;
    tagstruct.PlanarConfiguration = Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky;
    tagstruct.Software = 'MATLAB';
    t.setTag(tagstruct);
    t.write(image(:,:,1));
    numframes = size(image,3);
    divider = 10^(floor(log10(numframes))-1);
    tic
    for i=2:numframes
        t.writeDirectory();
        t.setTag(tagstruct);
        t.write(image(:,:,i));
        if (round(i/divider)==i/divider)
            fprintf('Frame %d written in %.0f seconds, %2d percent complete, time left=%.0f seconds \n', ...
                i, toc, i/numframes*100, (numframes - i)/(i/toc));
        end
    end
    t.close();
```

which results in the following output:

```
Frame 10000 written in 66 seconds, 8.196721e+00 percent complete, time left=743 seconds 
Frame 20000 written in 225 seconds, 1.639344e+01 percent complete, time left=1145 seconds 
Frame 30000 written in 481 seconds, 2.459016e+01 percent complete, time left=1474 seconds 
Frame 40000 written in 915 seconds, 3.278689e+01 percent complete, time left=1877 seconds 
Frame 50000 written in 1512 seconds, 4.098361e+01 percent complete, time left=2177 seconds
```

**Attempting to make use of the BigTIFF library does not work**

Following the discussion here:
http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2013/08/07/tiff-bigtiff-and-blockproc/

I attempted to convert the code to work with uint16 data by changing line 73 to:

```
    obj.TiffObject.setTag('BitsPerSample', 16);
```

but after writing with

```
outFileWriter = bigTiffWriter('test.tif', inFileInfo(1).Height, inFileInfo(1).Width, tileSize(1), tileSize(2));
for i=1:122000
    blockproc(IMG(:,:,i),tileSize,@(b) b.data,'Destination',outFileWriter);
    if rem(i,10000)==0
        fprintf('Frame %d done\n',i)
    end
end
```

I get the following error when trying to read back in:

```
Unexpected Standard exception from MEX file.
What() is:std::bad_alloc
..

Error in imtifinfo (line 27)
raw_tags = tifftagsread(filename,0,0,0);

Error in imfinfo (line 183)
info = feval(fmt_s.info, filename);

Error in TiffReader (line 11)
InfoImage=imfinfo(fname);
```

**On a related note, preallocating the file with the correct size on the disk makes no difference**

I thought there was a slim chance this was a file I/O problem, in which case preallocating the space on disk might be relevant, so I tried what was mentioned here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/241072, namely:

```
% Create the file
fh = javaObject('java.io.RandomAccessFile', 'test.dat', 'rw');
% Allocate the right amount of space
fh.setLength(1024);
% Close the file
fh.close();
```

but it made no difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Relevant: https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/07/30/tiff-update/ , https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/04/02/matlab-r2009a-imread-and-multipage-tiffs/

Comment: Also: Your use of `tic`/`toc` is wrong: You are measuring the time from starting to write the file to having written the frame, not the time for each frame!

Answer (score 2):

I also once ran into this problem. It seems Matlab 2018b has two .mexw64 files that can handle tiff writing.

`wtifc.mexw64` in `\toolbox\matlab\imagesci\private` called by `writetif.m`which is used by imwrite

and

`tifflib.mexw64`, same location, used by the Tiff object.

Both slow down with multi image tiff files. It is a lot faster to use `fwrite` to write all image data and end with the pointers to this data.

I tested three methods using this script and the difference is quite big.
This was done using matlab 2018b.

```
clear all;close all; clc; fclose all;
%generate some data
N=1E3;
IM=imread('landOcean.jpg');
IM = uint16(sum(IM,3));
IM = IM(100:310,960:1170);
IM = IM-min(IM(:));
IM=IM*(2^15/max(IM(:)));
IM = repmat(IM,[1,1,N])+randi((2^15)-1,[size(IM,1),size(IM,2),N],'uint16');
S = (numel(IM)/N*2)/2^20;


%imread writespeed
methods = {'imwrite','tifflib','fTIF'};
for M = 1:length(methods)
    method = methods{M};
    %file
    filename = [method,'.tif'];
    if exist(filename,'file'), delete(filename);end
    switch method
        case 'imwrite'
            %timing vector
            t = zeros(1,100+1);
            tic;
            imwrite(IM(:,:,1),filename);
            t(2)=toc;
            for ct = 2:100
                imwrite(IM(:,:,ct),filename,'WriteMode','append');
                t(ct+1)=toc;
            end
        case 'tifflib'
            %timing vector
            t = zeros(1,200+1);
            tic;
            tf = Tiff(filename,'w');
            for ct = 1:200
                if ct>1,tf.writeDirectory;end
                tf.setTag('Photometric',Tiff.Photometric.MinIsBlack);
                tf.setTag('Compression',Tiff.Compression.None);
                tf.setTag('BitsPerSample',16);
                tf.setTag('SamplesPerPixel',1);
                tf.setTag('SampleFormat',Tiff.SampleFormat.UInt);
                tf.setTag('ExtraSamples',Tiff.ExtraSamples.Unspecified);
                tf.setTag('ImageLength',size(IM,1));
                tf.setTag('ImageWidth',size(IM,2));
                tf.setTag('PlanarConfiguration',Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky);
                tf.setTag('ImageDescription',sprintf('ImageJ=1.51j\nchannels=%.0f',size(IM,3)));
                tf.write(IM(:,:,ct));
                t(ct)=toc;
            end
            tf.close();
        case 'fTIF'
            %timing vector
            t = zeros(1,size(IM,3)+1);
            tic
            fTIF = Fast_Tiff(filename);
            for ct = 1:size(IM,3)
                fTIF = fTIF.WriteIMG(IM(:,:,ct)');
                t(ct)=toc;
            end
            tic
            fTIF.close;
            toc
        otherwise
            error('unknown method')
    end
    S = (size(IM,1)*size(IM,2)*2)/2^20; %MB/frame
    y = S./diff(t);
    subplot(1,length(methods),M)
    plot([1:length(y)],y);
    title(sprintf('Writing with %s; mean = %.2f MB/s',method,mean(y)))
    ylabel('Writing speed (MB/s)')
    xlabel('Frame');
    drawnow;
end
```

[image: Speed Comparison]

Code for the fTIF method:

https://github.com/rharkes/Fast_Tiff_Write

Comment: Nice code! If `imread` doesn't read the file, there likely is a missing tag, or a tag with wrong format. Did you check the [TIFF 6.0 specification](https://www.itu.int/itudoc/itu-t/com16/tiff-fx/docs/tiff6.pdf)?

Comment: Thank you! I did check the tiff specification and thought I implemented all the tags correctly. Using `imfinfo` does give me the proper information. For BitDepth (a short) as well as StripByteCounts (a long). I can feed the pointers from imfinfo to fopen, fseek, fread to retrieve the data. But no reader will read the file except ImageJ. I will have a fresh look later and hopefully see the mistake.

Comment: It was a wrong compression tag. no compression = 1, not 0 as I expected.

Comment: Excellent! Glad you found it! It's a really nice bit of code, very well written and very useful! I'm pretty sure I'll need to "borrow" it at some point. ;)

Comment: That would be the best compliment! Please let me know if, while borrowing, you find anything that can be improved so I can implement it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, but it's even worse: even if you write another tiff, the time to write a frame is increasing.

So a solution (which works better on my case with multiple files) is to call the restart matlab session per shell command.

So in your "writeTIFF.m", you should have a variable "startFrame" and put an "exit" at the end of your script.
You can adress it with this kind of Batch (or equivalent under linux/unix) with this line :

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
:: count to 5 storing the results in a variable
set _tst=0
FOR /l %%G in (100,100,300) Do (
    echo matlab -r "startFrame=%%G;writeTIFF"  -nosplash -nodesktop -wait
    matlab -r "startFrame=%%G;writeTIFF"  -nosplash -nodesktop -wait
)
echo Done
```

I did not heavily tested, but it should do what's expected : restart matlab 3 times, and initialize the variable "startFrame" with the value 100, 200 and 300,  successively.